# how to update sideloaded app from playstore, when app is published in playstore

Tags: android, google-play, sideloading

I have an android app that will mostly be sideloaded from the apk obtained from over website, to use the GCM services we will also make the app available in play store, so if we update the app. Will the sideloaded app also get the auto updates as normal app do..

i have installed few apk directly but when the update comes they do auto update, so just want to make sure it is ok...

Comment: "i have installed few apk directly but when the update comes they do auto update"  Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: yes but was wondering whats the official take on this, or is this a hole that i going to be plugged very soon

Comment: You may be out of luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746330/android-sideloading-applications-and-keep-them-up-to-date-via-google-play